# Pandas Forward Fill NA only between two points and nothing else

Tags: python, pandas, series

I want to use pandas forward fill null values only between two non-null data points and nothing else.

For example I have a column named comments

```
Comments:
Hello World
NA
Hello World
NA 
Hello World
NA
NA
NA
NA
```

Output should look like this:

```
Hello World
Hello World
Hello World
Hello World
Hello World
NA
NA
NA
NA
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can calculate the last valid index and use `ffill` until this index:

```
last = df['Comments'].last_valid_index()

df['Comments'].loc[:last] = df['Comments'].loc[:last].ffill()

print(df)

      Comments
0  Hello World
1  Hello World
2  Hello World
3  Hello World
4  Hello World
5          NaN
6          NaN
7          NaN
8          NaN
```

Answer (score 1):

easiest way I found is to use interpolate:

```
df['Comments'] = df['Comments'].interpolate(method="pad")
```

This would not fill in NaN values at the beginning and at the end of the series.

Example:

```
s = pd.Series([np.nan,1,2,np.nan,np.nan,4, np.nan])

s = s.interpolate(method = "pad)

print(s)

0    NaN
1    1.0
2    2.0
3    2.0
4    2.0
5    4.0
6    NaN
dtype: float64
```

Comment: Evaluating your code shows `s.loc[6]` is not `NaN`